# Resetar o "<select>" ao desmarcar o checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá caros feras em Jquery, seguindo a lógica do exemplo abaixo, como fazer que o select sempre retorne ao primeiro valor da lista após desmarcar o respectivo checkbox?

E a segunda pergunta é se há uma forma melhor (mais simples) de se obter o mesmo resultado.

Achei que tinha conseguido, através de pergunta anterior porem apareceu erro.

Desde já, obrigado.

https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando jQuery basta fazer

```
select.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

assim: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/8/. Assim ele diz ao select para usar como escolha a `option` com index `0`, ou seja a primeira.

Também podes usar `select.val('');` que dá o mesmo efeito. Nalguns browsers esta solução não escolhe a primeira escolha mas sim deixa sem escolha, em branco.

Com JavaScript nativo seria `el.selectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: tu é fera! Uma outra pergunta: Seguindo essa lógica, como adicionar mais "itens" ao IF nesse formato? Por exemplo, como adicionar um "$('#id').show();" nessa linha?

Comment: @DaniloFagundes Dá uma olhada ao meu código, na tua versão estás a usar código a mais (redundante) e fica demasiado customizado. É melhor menter simples e usar o DOM, ou seja: procurar qual o select que está na mesma `<tr>` e não ir buscar o elemento pelo ID.

Comment: Entendi, fico um pouco perdido utilizando essa lógica mas por falta de conhecimento mesmo (costume). Por exemplo: nessa nova linha do código:  if (!this.checked) select.prop('selectedIndex', 0); , como fica a adição de um novo "item" nesse mesmo if ? um "$('#id').show();" por exemplo. Entendendo isso pra mim fica mais fácil de montar outros. Obrigado ;)

Comment: @DaniloFagundes o que queres dizer com "novo item"? queres mudar mais do que um select de cada vez?

Comment: imaginemos um <span id="texto1">, seguindo sua dica, como ocultar o span ao selecionar qualquer um dos "checkbox" e mostrar o span quando não haver nenhuma seleção? Assim acredito que entenderei como funciona o if e else nesse código. segue: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/11/

Comment: @DaniloFagundes nesse caso o mais simples é verificar se a soma é `>0`... é pelo menos o mais prático, assim: `$('#texto1').toggle(!sum);`: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/12/ mas também podes usar `.filter()`, que dá o mesmo resultado: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/13/

Comment: Endendi, e qual seria a alternativa usando o estado "checked" do checkbox? Segue, nesse acho que ficou mais claro: https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/15/ ... com isso termino aqui. Desde já muito obrigado pela aula de hoje e desculpe qualquer coisa, sou iniciante aqui.

Comment: @DaniloFagundes https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/16/, eu prefiro não usar IDs. Dá uma olhada à sugestão. Se não compreenderes faz uma nova pergunta que vais receber ajuda. Fiz umas correções ao teu exemplo, mas a chave é `eq()` que escolhe um elemento entre os encontrados, e recebe o `i` que é o index dos inputs. Assim desde que haja 1 `span.aviso` para cada input esse código funciona, independentemente da quantidade.

Comment: perfeito. Seguindo seu exemplo consegui incluir algumas ações na função, a soma em paralelo só dos selects, ocultar o subtotal se o respectivo selectbox não estiver selecionado, ocultar o total (se a soma for zero), https://jsfiddle.net/8uk440do/18/ , funcionou perfeitamente, vou abrir uma nova pergunta para que possam me orientar se há alguma parte com redundância no codigo. Com base em suas respostas anteriores, provavelmente há.  obrigado pela ajuda ;)

Comment: Bom dia Sergio. Basicamente o que altera para a utilização da metodologia each() em uma estrutura de "divs", sem estrutura de table, tfoot, tr... ? Estou aqui tentando aplicar o ultimo aprendizado que vocês me passaram porem esbarrei nessa dificuldade.

Comment: @DaniloFagundes tens um exemplo no jsFiddle dessa estrutura?

Comment: Olá fera, seguindo a lógica que me passou e na base de tentativa e erro consegui fazer funcionar. Consegui incluir o bootstrap também, pra mim isso tudo é novo, por isso desculpe se as vezes eu perguntar demais. Segue o link do modelo funcionado sem a estrutura de table. https://jsfiddle.net/yne288ar/ tentei otimizar mais porem apareceram erros. Obrigado pelas aulas Sergio

Comment: @DaniloFagundes boa! Não vejo erros, parece-me bem à primeira vista.

Answer (score 2):

A linha comentada no seu exemplo:

```
// $('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

já tava bem perto da solução. O problema é que `$('select')` retorna todos os selects da página, e aí todos eram reiniciados quando qualquer checkbox era marcado.

Você pode restringir apenas para o select dentro da célula que você está escondendo. Só usar o `id` da célula dela:

```
$('#e' + index + ' select').prop('selectedIndex', 0)
```

Comment: Gabe usando um ID para cada `td` soa-me a demasiado customizado. Acho mais simples ir pelas relações de parentesco no DOM do que ter IDs em cada `td` que são strings que precisam de ser trabalhadas para usar somente pedaços.

Comment: @Sergio Concordo plenamente. Tentei só aproveitar o máximo possível do código que já estava lá, pra ajudar na compreensão, mas o código na sua resposta é definitivamente mais "elegante"

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma bem fácil de fazer isso, por exemplo, pelo `value` da opção que você quer selecionar...no exemplo eu seleciono o `value` vazio:

```
$('#id option[value=""]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```